# How do I set my Run/Debug Configurations for apps on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I set my Run/Debug Configurations for apps on Android Studio?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkkQA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvsyi.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you obtained that code, but it seems to be written in C# rather than for an Android Studio project. This could be why you're unable to run or debug it. By default, the IDE typically displays the Android view on the left, but in your case, it's showing the Project view instead. From what I can tell, the code doesn't appear to be intended for Android development at all

Comment: The code argon is from GitHub.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).